# different dropdown lists in a column in gridview

Tags: asp.net, gridview

I have a `gridview` and in it I have a column that contains `dropdownlist`. I can't have different `dropdownlist` items for every row, and items of each row `dropdownlist` is the same. I want that my first row `dropdownlist` has item for example {1,2,3}, {2,3,5,7} for second row, and etc. I don't want to have the same `dropdownlist` for each row but I don't know how to do that.
thanks in advance

```
Protected Sub GridView2_RowDataBound(sender As Object, e As GridViewRowEventArgs) Handles GridView2.RowDataBound
    If (e.Row.RowType = DataControlRowType.DataRow) Then
        Dim list_color As DropDownList = CType(e.Row.FindControl("colorList"), DropDownList)
        Dim dt3 As New DataTable
            Dim adapter As New OleDbDataAdapter("SELECT ID, name FROM color WHERE ID IN (" & GridView2.Rows(index).Cells(10).Text.ToString & ")", conn)
            adapter.Fill(dt3)
            list_color.DataSource = dt3
            list_color.DataTextField = "name"
            list_color.DataValueField = "name"
            list_color.DataBind()
    End If
End Sub
```

Comment: your question was not clear. You first said you cant have different items for each row, and later said you have different values for each row. please add more details.

Comment: I want to place the value of a hidden column in row(x) to the drop down list of row(x) as items